# Application pool recycling with Selfhosting a ASP.NET application

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api, owin, self-hosting

If I want to selfhost a asp.net web api application with Owin in a windows service, how can I integrate kind of a application pool recycling that IIS offers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simple: you cannot. Application pool is an IIS feature that you can only enjoy by hosting on IIS.

Comment: So wat is the purpose of selfhosting then? This is an important feature you do not want to develop yourself...,

Comment: @Pascal self-hosting is only used in those scenarios when you cannot use IIS.

Comment: ok but still when can I not use IIS ? I am forced to use Linux? Then I wont choose asp.net at least not before asp vnext. Self-Hosted makes no sense to me then its just a big compromise.

Comment: @Pascal there are web servers on Linux that support ASP.NET, which either provide application pools directly such as Jexus, or use FastCGI to simulate the pool such as nginx. You simply need to learn those Linux specific ways, and don't be bind to IIS alone.

Comment: Ok fine did not know that. So its jexus + mono.